# Upload DataFrame to AWS S3 bucket in Julia

Tags: amazon-s3, julia

It should be straightforward, but I could not find an example online as to what function/method to use. I am trying to upload a DataFrame object to an AWS S3 bucket in Julia. Do I need to save it first and then upload the file? I am using `AWS` and `AWSS3` packages. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(answer to comment)

You can compress in-memory like this:

```
using CodecZlib, TranscodingStreams

buf = IOBuffer()
stream = GzipCompressorStream(buf)
CSV.write(stream, table)
write(stream, TranscodingStreams.TOKEN_END)
flush(stream)
compressed_data = take!(buf)
close(stream)
# now put compressed_data to S3
```